# Rock, paper, scissors game in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I am trying to get this program to run:

```
cpucount = 0
playercount = 0
tiecount = 0

playerchoice = 

while playerchoice != "n" 
  puts "Chose your Weapon. Paper (0), Rock (1), Scissors (2)"
  player1 = 0 #gets
  cpuplayer = 2#rand(3)
  puts player1
  puts cpuplayer
  if player1 == 0 and cpuplayer == 1
    puts "You Win"
    playercount +=1
  elsif player1 == 1 and cpuplayer == 2
    puts "You Win!"
    playercount +=1
  elsif player1 == 2 and cpuplayer == 0
    puts "You Win!"
    playercount +=1
  elsif player1 == cpuplayer
    puts "You tied!"
    tiecount +=1
  else
    puts "You lose"
    cpucount +=1
  end
  puts cpucount
  puts playercount
  puts tiecount
  puts "Do you want to play again? y/n?"
  playerchoice = gets
  puts playerchoice
end
```

but there are a few issues.

First, regardless of whether I select `"y"` to continue to another round or `"n"` to quit, it still runs another round.

Second, the logic is fine when I manually input the values for player1 and cpuplayer, but when I use the rand method and the user input, the program takes those and then the logic doesn't work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: When dealing with multiple conditions, try something like `case ([ player1, cpuplayer ])` and then branch out like `when [ 0, 1 ]` and so forth to handle the clauses. This reads a lot easier than a sprawling pile of `if` statements. Also watch out. `playerchoice = nil` is required earlier on, otherwise it assigns to the result of the `while`.

Comment: I looked at a piece of sample code while I was working on this that utilized what you explained. I will play around more with that in the future, but for now all I know how to do is if-then, but thank you for the feedback!

Comment: There are some answers to [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32105234/drying-up-rock-paper-scissors) that you might find interesting.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your input statement which is using `gets` you need to take into account the newline that is placed in the string, and the fact that it is a string. When the player is inputting it, it is coming in as text, not an integer. A simple way to do this is to make it an integer on input, via

```
player1 = gets.to_i
```

That will guarantee that the conditional logic you use to test against integers is not going to fail because you are comparing a string.

The newline that is coming in with the `playerchoice` input needs get chomped to make that happy for comparison. So, there is another method to get rid of newlines.

```
playerchoice = gets.chomp
```

Comment: Thank you, that fixed the logic issue!

Answer (score 0):

Try assigning the `playerchoice` variable in the following way:

```
playerchoice = gets.chomp
```

The `#gets` method by itself will output any carriage returns that come with the user's input, which is why if you were to inspect the returned value for `playerchoice`, you'd see that instead of `"n"`, the value returned is actually `"n\n"`, causing your comparison to resume looping the game. Calling `#chomp` on that value strips out the carriage return characters (\n, \r, \r\n), which should allow the game to end if "n" is typed in by the user.

Hope it helps!

Comment: thank you! I was trying to use chomp earlier and was getting some error about a constant, I was just using it wrong it seems.

any idea about the conditionals?